# SQL Query to Count number of values in a column Per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
id   date          sales
1    01/01/2015    100
2    01/01/2015    100
3    02/01/2015    100
4    03/01/2015    100
```

What I need is to count the number of sales in a given date range (per month)which is based user input which are StartDate and EndDate. For Example the User inputs StartDate - 01/01/2015 and EndDate - 04/01/2015

the output would be like this

```
Month  StartMonth  EndMonth     TotalSales
1      01/01/2015  01/31/2015   200
2      02/01/2015  02/28/2015   100
3      03/01/2015  03/31/2015   100
4      04/01/2015  04/30/2015   0
```

Started to something like this

```
set @Start_act = cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @StartDate), 0) as date)
    set @End_act = cast(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Enddate)+1, 0)) as date)



    set @counter = DATEDIFF(month, @Start_act, @End_act)
    if(@counter = 1)
    begin
        set @counter = @counter
    end
    else
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

    set @count = 0

    CREATE TABLE #TempTableID
    (
        Month int,  
        StartMonth date, 
        EndMonth date,
        TotalSales  
    )

    while (@count <= @counter)
    begin

        set @count = @count + 1;

        if(@count = 1)
        begin
            set @Start = @Start_act
            set @End = cast(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Start_act)+1, 0)) as date)
            set @plannedHorseCapacity = 123
        end
        else
        begin
            set @Start = cast(DATEADD(d, 1, @End)as date)
            set @End = cast(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Start)+1, 0)) as date)
            set @plannedHorseCapacity = 456
        end

        Insert into #TempTableID
        (
            Month  
            StartMonth 
            EndMonth 
            TotalSales 
        )
        Values
        (
            @count,
            @Start,
            @End,
            @TotalSales

        )

        if(@count > @counter)
        begin
            break
        end
        else
        begin           
            continue
        end
    end

    Select * from #TempTableID
```

Comment: What is your sql-server version

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below script -

```
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MONTH([date]))
+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR([date])) monthyear
,([sales])

FROM [sales])
--add where condition for from and to date here
SELECT
monthyear
,SUM(sales) totalsales
FROM cte
GROUP BY monthyear
```

Output will be

```
monthyear   totalsales
1-2015  400
2-2015  50
3-2015  150
```

**Option 2 With Start and End Date**

```
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
    FORMAT(MONTH([date]), '0#')

    + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR([date])) monthyear
    ,([sales])

FROM [sales])
--add where condition for from and to date here
SELECT
monthyear
,cast (SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 2) as int) [Month]
,SUBSTRING(monthyear, 4, 4) [Year]
,(SELECT
       DATEADD(MONTH, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 2) - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 4, 4) - 1900, 0)))
StartDate
,(SELECT
       DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 2) AS INT), DATEADD(YEAR, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 4, 4) - 1900, 0))))
EndDate
,SUM(sales) totalsales
FROM cte
GROUP BY monthyear
```

**Output will be**

```
monthyear Month Year StartDate              EndDate                   totalsales
01-2015   1   2015  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000   400
02-2015   2   2015  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 2015-02-28 00:00:00.000   50
03-2015   3   2015  2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-31 00:00:00.000   50
11-2015  11   2015  2015-11-01 00:00:00.000 2015-11-30 00:00:00.000   100
```

**EDIT - Sorting**

If you have multiple year data, then the dates will not come in sequence to fix that add `order by [StartDate]` in last.

output will be

```
monthyear Month Year    StartDate    EndDate                   totalsales
01-2015   1   2015  2015-01-01 00:00:00  2015-01-31 00:00:00.000    400
02-2015   2   2015  2015-02-01 00:00:00  2015-02-28 00:00:00.000    50
03-2015   3   2015  2015-03-01 00:00:00  2015-03-31 00:00:00.000    50
11-2015  11   2015  2015-11-01 00:00:00  2015-11-30 00:00:00.000    100
01-2016   1   2016  2016-01-01 00:00:00  2016-01-31 00:00:00.000    125
11-2016  11   2016  2016-11-01 00:00:00  2016-11-30 00:00:00.000    55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this,

```
;WITH [CTE_DATE]
AS
(
    SELECT  MONTH(@fromdt) AS [Month]
            ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @fromdt), 0)   AS StartMonth
            ,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@fromdt)+1,0))   AS EndMonth
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  [Month] + 1 AS [Month]
            ,DATEADD(MONTH,1,StartMonth)    AS StartMonth
            ,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH,1,StartMonth))+1,0))       AS EndMonth
    FROM [CTE_DATE] WHERE [Month] < MONTH(@todt)
)


SELECT  *
        ,(SELECT SUM(sales) FROM yourtable where [date] between StartMonth and EndMonth) as  TotalSales
FROM [CTE_DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find end of month as below:

```
select [Month] = Month([date]), [date] as StartMonth, 
        EndMonth = convert(date, dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,'2017-02-11')+1,0)-1),
        TotalSales from (
    select [date],  sum(sales) as totalSales 
        from #yoursales
        group by [date]
        ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   id int, 
   [date] date,
   sales int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
( 1 , '2015-01-01', 100 ),
( 2 , '2015-01-01', 100 ),
( 3 , '2015-02-01', 100 ),
( 4 , '2015-03-01', 100 )

DECLARE @StartDate date = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '2015-08-01'

;WITH temp AS -- calendar table
(
   SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@StartDate),0) AS [StartMonthDate],
        dateadd(day, -1 ,dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@StartDate) + 1,0)) AS [EndMonthDate]

   UNION ALL

   SELECT dateadd(month, 1, t.[StartMonthDate]),
        dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, 2, t.[StartMonthDate])) 
   FROM temp t
   WHERE dateadd(month, 1, t.[StartMonthDate]) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT  datepart(year,t.StartMonthDate) AS year,
      datepart(month,t.StartMonthDate) AS month,
      t.StartMonthDate,
      t.EndMonthDate,
      coalesce(ap.TotalSales,0) AS TotalSales
FROM temp t
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT SUM(sales)  AS TotalSales
   FROM @SampleData sd
   WHERE sd.[date] BETWEEN t.StartMonthDate AND t.EndMonthDate

) ap
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/LWUX67185

Comment: Hi, month and Start and EndMonth should be automatic, dynamic and not manually encoded

Comment: Then what did you see in my answer non-automatic, or non-dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(id,date,sales)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'01/01/2015',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'01/01/2015',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'02/01/2015',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'03/01/2015',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'04/01/2015',NULL 
)
SELECT [Id],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[DATE], 101) AS [DATE],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[EndMonth],101) AS [EndMonth],
[SumOfSale] From
(
SELECT id,[DATE],EndMonth,SUM(sales) OVER(Partition by [DATE],EndMonth order by EndMonth) AS SumOfSale,
Row_NUmber ()OVER(Partition by [DATE],EndMonth order by id)As Seq From
(
SELECT id, CAST([DATE] AS DATE)[DATE], EOMONTH(date)AS EndMonth,ISNULL(sales,0)As Sales from cte
)Dt 
)Final 
WHERE Final.Seq=1
```

OutPut

```
Month  StartMonth  EndMonth     TotalSales
1      01/01/2015  01/31/2015   200
2      02/01/2015  02/28/2015   100
3      03/01/2015  03/31/2015   100
4      04/01/2015  04/30/2015   0
```

Comment: Hi, month and Start and EndMonth should be automatic, dynamic and not manually encoded

Comment: I made date column alias of start date and End of month